# Delegate Variance in c++/cli

Tags: c#, c++-cli, covariance, contravariance

I am in the process of converting working C# code into C++/CLI, and I'm having trouble understanding why it does not compile.

The error I received:

`void MyNamespace::Handler::DataChanged(System::Object ^,System::EventArgs ^)' : the specified function does not match the delegate type 'void (System::Object ^,System::Data::DataRowChangeEventArgs ^)'`

Comment: What version of VC++?  The function IS compatible with the delegate, if you report this on MS Connect I will definitely upvote it.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I'm using 2010. I've never used/reported on MS Connect before..

Comment: @Ben Voigt: This not compiling (even though it's valid as you say) threatens my whole inheritance model. <sigh> very sad.

Comment: Something screwy with your code... inline members shouldn't have qualified names.  I'm guessing your real code doesn't have this problem?

Comment: Nope.. I don't have it in my code.. not sure why I typed it here. lol thanks good catch.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like C++/CLI doesn't support parameter variance for delegates as C# and VB do, see [this  Microsoft connect bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/574318/vc-2010-c-cli-does-not-support-variant-delegates-interfaces#).

As a work around your can wrap your call to handler in a wrapper that takes a DataRowChangeEventArgs and calls your handler:

```
public ref class MyClass
{
....
public:
    void MyClass::Delegates(DataTable ^table)
    {
        Handler ^handler = gcnew Handler();
        DataRowChangeEventForwarder& forwarder = 
             gcnew DataRowChangeEventForwarder(
             new EventHandler(handler, &MyNamespace::Handler::DataChanged)));
        table->RowChanged += gcnew DataRowChangeEventHandler (forwarder, &MyNamespace::MyClass::RowChangedDelegate);
    }
 }

 public ref class DataRowChangeEventForwarder 
 {
 private:
     EventHandler^ eventHandler;
 public:
     EventForwarder(EventHandler^ eventHandler) 
     {
          this->eventHandler = eventHander;
     }

     void MyClass::RowChangedDelegate(Object ^sender, DataRowEventArgs ^arg)
     {
          handler->DataChanged(sender, arg);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Probably better to put that forwarder into the `Handler` class, or store a `Handler^`.  Allocating a new `Handler` instance is almost certainly the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, yeah that was a pretty bad example.  I've updated the example snippet with something more correct, which I believe still has the same semantics as the code in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm certainly extremely irritated that it isn't supported! <sigh>. However, I don't think I'll be wrapping as you suggest - It would create just as much code as would creating separate handlers for each type of EventArg... :S

Comment: Actually, that bug report is something else entirely, it's related to covariant/contravariant use of a delegate after creation.  This question is about creation of a delegate from a function with parameter contravariance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete compile-ready reproduction of the bug (would be a comment, but the formatting would be horrid):

```
public ref struct A
{
};

public ref struct B : A
{
};

public ref struct C
{
    delegate void DType(B^);
    void F(A^ a) { };
};

int main(void)
{
    C^ c = gcnew C;
    C::DType^ del = gcnew C::DType(c, &C::F);
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure how this would help me, considering that I am not creating my own types, but using existing .NET ones such as DataTable, and XmlNode etc. which then in turn have different event arguments such as DataRowChangeEventArgs, DataTableNewRowEventArgs, etc.

Comment: @developer: This causes the same error your code does.  But unlike the code in your question, this repro is complete and self-contained.  It's here to make it easier for others to study the problem.  And like I said, I posted it as an answer only because comments can't contain code blocks.

Comment: @developer: The glaring errors in your code (`class MyClass { void MyClass::Delegates(); };` is incorrect, don't qualify names with `MyClass::` inside the class body also motivated me to make a shorter example without all those problems.

Comment: Ah, I assumed it was an "answer".. skipped over reading the first sentence where you stated it's a reproduction! Sorry.. I was reading the code as something you wanted me to try. Maybe a better placement would be an edit of my question (as opposed to an "answer").

Comment: Also, yea I'm not sure why I wrote the qualifying names.. possible copy/paste error? I'll take em out of my question.

Comment: @developer: That wording changed (originally said simply "compile-ready example") although the meaning didn't.  I guess I could have stuck it into your question, but I use my editing rights very sparingly.